# Android writing Unit test for utility methods

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit

I am writing unit test for a static utility method:

```
public static String getString(Object object, boolean prettyPrint) {
    if (object == null) {
        throw new NullPointerException("Cannot pass null to Utility.getString() method");
    }
    Gson gson;
    if (prettyPrint) {
        gson = new GsonBuilder().setPrettyPrinting().create();
    } else {
        gson = new Gson();
    }
    return gson.toJson(object);
}
```

Here's the unit test:

```
@Test 
public void getString() throws Exception {
    JokeItem item = new JokeItem("title", "joke");
    String required = new Gson().toJson(item);
    String actual = Utility.getString(item, false);
    Assert.assertEquals(required, actual);
    String required1 = "{\"joke\":\"joke\",\"title\":\"title\"}";
    String actual1 = Utility.getString(item, false);
    Assert.assertEquals(required1, actual1);
}
```

`JokeItem` is a simple pojo class. The problem I am facing is that I am not sure if my test case if the right way to test this method because I am basically using the same method `gson.toJson(object)` in both the methods.It would be very helpful if I could get some insights in testing this kind of functions and pitfalls and inadequacies in my approach.

Comment: If you're using Google's `gson`, why are you unit-testing it? I only test code I can actively change/refactor and rely when using third-party libraries upon the respective developer to test them themselves. The only deviation is when I discover bugs in the library myself and want to prove it.

Comment: The right way is to do `new Gson().toJson(item); ` because when u have more properties in your `JokeItem` you would probably need to change ur custom i.e `required1`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Testing such methods is actually pretty easy - you create a series of tests that call the method with specific input; and then you check what is coming back. Like:

```
@Test(expected=NullPointerException.class)
public testCtorWithNullStringAndTrue() {
  Whatever.getString(null, true);
}
// same for false

// and then
public testSomeInput() {
  assertThat(Whatever.getString("whatever", true), is("expected-json-string"));
} // same for false ...
```

Probably you won't need much more than that - as Marek has pointed out; you should not starting Gson implementations.

But: you definitely want to test **all possible** paths within your method; in your case you simply want to make sure that you get back some expected output for a certain, fixed input (including all different kinds of "invalid" input!).

Finally, on code quality: it is tempting to write such little helpers as static methods; and to use a boolean as argument, **but** ... this is not a good OO design. Consider this:

```
interface JsonBuilder {
   String getString(Object input);
}

class SimpleBuilder implements JsonBuilder 
// does what your "non-pretty print code" does

class PrettyBuilder implements JsonBuilder
// does the other thing
```

And instead of worrying about using true/false; and **tightly** coupling the users of that static method to the implementation (hard to break up later on); you can just pass around objects of the JsonBuilder interface.
And your code just calls that one method, without further worrying.

Maybe overkill here, but still an approach worth thinking about.

Answer (score 3):

Unit-testing `Gson` doesn't make sense - it is already tested by it's authors.
As your method is quite simple I would say that only first `if` statement should be tested and checked if `NullPointerException` is thrown when passing null object.
If you want to create stronger test I would suggest to check interactions with `Gson` and `GsonBuilder`, to verify if correct methods have been invoked. But that would require spying on both objects.